# How is an sbt task defined using <<= different from one defined with := that references another setting's .value?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following example build.sbt that uses `sbt-assembly`. (My assembly.sbt and project/assembly.sbt are set up as described in the [readme](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).)

```
import AssemblyKeys._

organization := "com.example"

name := "hello-sbt"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Prints hello")

hello := println(s"hello, ${assembly.value.getName}")

val hey = taskKey[Unit]("Prints hey")

hey <<= assembly map { (asm) => println(s"hey, ${asm.getName}") }

//val hi = taskKey[Unit]("Prints hi")

//hi <<= assembly { (asm) => println(s"hi, $asm") }
```

Both `hello` and `hey` are functionally equivalent, and when I run either task from sbt, they run `assembly` first and print a message with the same filename. **Is there a meaningful difference between the two?** (It seems like the definition of `hello` is "slightly magical", since the dependency on assembly is only implied there, not explicit.)

Lastly, I'm trying to understand why `hey` needs the `map` call. Obviously it results in a different object getting passed into `asm`, but I'm not quite sure how to fix this type error in the definition of `hi`:

```
sbt-hello/build.sbt:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: sbt.Task[Unit]
hi <<= assembly { (asm) => println(s"hi, $asm") }
                                  ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

It looks like `assembly` here is a `[sbt.TaskKey[java.io.File]][2]` but I don't see a `map` method defined there, so I can't quite figure out what's happening in the type of `hey` above.

Comment: Using sbt 0.13 and scala 2.10, in case it matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### sbt 0.12 syntax vs sbt 0.13 syntax

> Is there a meaningful difference between the two?

By *meaningful difference*, if you mean *semantic difference* as in observable difference in the behavior of the compiled code, they are the same.

If you mean, any intended differences in code, it's about the style difference between sbt 0.12 syntax sbt 0.13 syntax. Conceptually, I think sbt 0.13 syntax makes it easier to learn and code since you deal with `T` instead of `Initialize[T]` directly. Using macro, sbt 0.13 expands `x.value` into sbt 0.12 equivalent.

### anatomy of <<=

> I'm trying to understand why hey needs the map call.

That's actually one of the difference macro now is able to handle automatically.
To understand why `map` is needed in sbt 0.12 style, you need to understand the type of sbt DSL expression, which is `Setting[_]`. As [Getting Started guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html) puts it:

> Instead, the build definition creates a huge list of objects with type `Setting[T]` where `T` is the type of the value in the map. A `Setting` describes a *transformation to the map*, such as adding a new key-value pair or appending to an existing value.

For tasks, the type of DSL expression is `Setting[Task[T]]`. To turn a setting key into `Setting[T]`, or to turn a task key into `Setting[Task[T]]`, you use `<<=` method defined on respective keys. This is implemented in [Structure.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.12.0/main/Structure.scala) (sbt 0.12 code base has simpler implementation of `<<=` so I'll be using that as the reference.):

```
sealed trait SettingKey[T] extends ScopedTaskable[T] with KeyedInitialize[T] with Scoped.ScopingSetting[SettingKey[T]] with Scoped.DefinableSetting[T] with Scoped.ListSetting[T, Id] { ... }

sealed trait TaskKey[T] extends ScopedTaskable[T] with KeyedInitialize[Task[T]] with Scoped.ScopingSetting[TaskKey[T]] with Scoped.ListSetting[T, Task] with Scoped.DefinableTask[T] { ... }

object Scoped {
    sealed trait DefinableSetting[T] {
        final def <<= (app: Initialize[T]): Setting[T]  =  setting(scopedKey, app)
        ...
    }

    sealed trait DefinableTask[T] { self: TaskKey[T] =>
        def <<= (app: Initialize[Task[T]]): Setting[Task[T]]  =  Project.setting(scopedKey, app)
        ...
    }
}
```

Note the types of `app` parameters. Setting key's `<<=` takes `Initialize[T]` whereas the task key's `<<=` takes `Initialize[Task[T]]`. In other words, depending on the the type of lhs of an `<<=` expression the type of rhs changes. This requires sbt 0.12 users to be aware of the setting/task difference in the keys.

Suppose you have a setting key like `description` on the lhs, and suppose you want to depend on `name` setting and create a description. To create a setting dependency expression you use `apply`:

```
description <<= name { n => n + " is good." }
```

`apply` for a single key is implemented in [Settings.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.12.0/util/collection/Settings.scala):

```
sealed trait Keyed[S, T] extends Initialize[T]
{
    def transform: S => T
    final def apply[Z](g: T => Z): Initialize[Z] = new GetValue(scopedKey, g compose transform)
}
trait KeyedInitialize[T] extends Keyed[T, T] {
    final val transform = idFun[T]
}
```

Next, instead of `description`, suppose you want to create a setting for `jarName in assembly`. This is a task key, so rhs of `<<=` takes `Initialize[Task[T]]`, so `apply` is not good. This is where `map` comes in:

```
jarName in assembly <<= name map { n => n + ".jar" }
```

This is implemented in [Structure.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.12.0/main/Structure.scala) as well:

```
final class RichInitialize[S](init: Initialize[S]) {
    def map[T](f: S => T): Initialize[Task[T]] = init(s => mktask(f(s)) )
}
```

Because a setting key extends `KeyedInitialize[T]`, which is `Initialize[T]`, and because there's an implicit conversion from `Initialize[T]` to `RichInitialize[T]` the above is available to `name`. This is an odd way of defining `map` since maps usually preserves the structure.

It might make more sense, if you see similar enrichment class for task keys:

```
final class RichInitializeTask[S](i: Initialize[Task[S]]) extends RichInitTaskBase[S, Task] {...}

sealed abstract class RichInitTaskBase[S, R[_]] {
    def map[T](f: S => T): Initialize[R[T]] = mapR(f compose successM)
}
```

So for tasks, `map` maps from a task of type `S` to `T`. For settings, we can think of it as: `map` is not defined on a setting, so it implicitly converts itself to a task and maps that. In any case, this let's sbt 0.12 users to think: Use `apply` for settings, `map` for tasks. Note that `apply` ever goes away for task keys as they extend `Keyed[Task[T], Task[T]]`. This should explain:

```
sbt-hello/build.sbt:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: sbt.Task[Unit]
```

Then there's the tuple issue. So far I've discussed dependencies to a single setting. If you want to depend on more, sbt implicitly adds `apply` and `map` to `Tuple2..N` to handle it. Now it's [expanded to 15](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/07fd9ab57e629e2ce32dda982c7488990c92d12e), but it used to be up till only `Tuple9`. Seeing from a new user's point of view, the idea of invoking `map` on a `Tuple9` of settings so it generates a task-like `Initialize[Task[T]]` would appear alien. Without changing the underlying mechanism, sbt 0.13 provides much cleaner surface to get started.

Comment: Thanks! This is a fantastic answer. I'm going to have to read it a few times to fully grasp everything.