# What does "<<=" do in sbt settings?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am learning to write some more advanced sbt build files, and I came across [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/SbtProguard.scala)'s code:

```
  binaryDeps <<= compile in Compile map { _.relations.allBinaryDeps.toSeq },
  inputs <<= fullClasspath in Runtime map { _.files },
  libraries <<= (binaryDeps, inputs) map { (deps, in) => deps filterNot in.toSet },
  outputs <<= artifactPath map { Seq(_) },
```

- I want to know what does **<<=** mean in this context?
- How do I understand the *map* function at the 3rd line?

Comment: In a more recent build (sbt >= 0.13), we would write it in a simpler way: `libraries := binaryDeps.value filterNot inputs.value.toSet`.

Comment: See [How is an sbt task defined using <<= different from one defined with := that references another setting's .value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642575/how-is-an-sbt-task-defined-using-different-from-one-defined-with-that-ref).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<=` is a method on [DefinableSetting](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.Scoped$$DefinableSetting) (mixed in by [TaskKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.TaskKey), [InputKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.InputKey), and [SettingKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.SettingKey)) which provides a way to initialise a build setting. It's described in the older docs [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Dormant/Basic-Configuration.html#more-information):

```
:= assigns a value, overwriting any existing value. <<= uses existing values to initialize a setting.
```

Essentially, in 0.12 (and current versions, for compatibility) it was a way to define a build setting in terms of some other build setting(s).

As @sjrd points out, in 0.13 a [new task setting syntax](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#new-task-setting-syntax) was introduced allowing you to do this with `:=` instead.

The `map` in the third line is creating a new settings value by getting only dependency items from `binaryDeps` which are not already in `inputs`, i.e. *transform* these two settings into this new one.